# How to replace a substring with another string in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column as below:

```
df['name']
1                              react trainer
2                              react trainers
3                              react trainer's
```

I need to replace the string trainers/trainer's to trainer:

```
1                              react trainer
2                              react trainer
3                              react trainer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['name'].str.replace('trainer(\'?s)*', 'trainer')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['name'].str.replace(to_replace ='trainer.*', value = 'trainer', regex = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both find rows with this substring and return the substring itself, you should use regex. I have that below

```
import re

def return_substr(string,substring)
  #Check substring
  if re.search(substring,string):
     return(substring)
  #If not found, return ‘’
  else:
     return(‘’)

#Use apply to run this row by row
df[‘replaceCol’] = df[‘Name’].apply(lambda x: return_substr(x,’react trainer’), axis=1)
```